# How do I split individual months in xarray?

Tags: python, jupyter, python-xarray

I have a 3D data set (time in months, y, and x) and I want to use xarray to group all months together.
I am expecting to have a data array that is months (1 - 12), # years for that month only, y, and x. How do I achieve that using xarray?

I tried the groupby function, however it outputs no shape (in the form of month, years, y and x):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ds = xr.tutorial.open_dataset('rasm').load()

ds_split_months = ds.groupby('time.month')

#print(ds_split_months.shape)
ds_split_months
```

What I am trying to achieve is to work with a new xarray dataframe which has:
number of months (January - December), all the years of that month (so in this case it's 3 years), y and x spatial location.

I get the typical xarray data frame when I include:

```
ds_split_months = ds.groupby('time.month').mean() #or .sum()
```

but I do not want to average of sum over those years. I just want to reshape the data to
12 months, number of years, y and x.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Using `groupby` gives you a `DatasetGroupBy` object that you can perform reductions on.

Comment: I'll update the question to include what I'm trying to achieve :)

Comment: let me know if that clarifies. I'm trying to avoid using numpy and just stick with xarray

Comment: Hmmm not sure - so you want to go from `(x, y, time)` to `(x, y, month, year)`. If so, why? And what is your next step?

Comment: Reshaping from `(x, y, time)` to `(x, y, month, year)` has an answer here: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/discussions/5119#discussioncomment-581232